# Bi grams creating and counting of the probability of the word occurrence

Tags: python, dictionary, probability, n-gram

I am trying to build a bigram model and to calculate the probability of word occurence. I should
•Select an appropriate data structure to store bigrams.
• increment counts for a combination of word and previous word. This means I need to keep track of what the previous word was.
• compute the probability of the current word based on the previous word count.

Prob  of  curr  word  = count(prev  word,  curr  word)/ count(previous word)

Consider we observed the following word sequences:
finger remarked 
finger on 
finger on 
finger in 
finger . Notice that "finger on " was observed twice. Also, notice that the period is treated as a separate word.Given the  information in  this data  structure,  we  can compute  the probability (on|finger) as   2/5   =   0.4.
Here is what I got so far:

```
filename = 'blah-blah.txt'
bigrams ={}
prev_word = "START"

# opening the filename in read mode
with open(filename, "r") as fp:
    for line in fp:

        words = line.split()

        for word in words:
            word = word.lower()
            bigram = prev_word + ' ' + word

            if bigram in bigrams:
                bigrams[bigram] += 1

            else:
                bigrams[bigram] = 1
                prev_word = word
                #print(bigram)

for k, v in bigrams.items():
    probability = v/1

    print(k + ':' + str(probability))
```

But I stuck at the moment how I can keep track the previous word to count the probability. I just put 1 here "probability = v/1" just to figure out what exactly I have to do next. 
Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0):

with this formula:

Prob of curr word = count(prev word, curr word)/ count(previous word)..

and if the "previous word" is the total occurrence of the previous word in the document then you might want to just create another dictionary for your vocab where the occurrences of the words that you have is stored. :)

like

```
vocab = {'my_word' : num_occurences}
```